# which variables needed for the tomcats server

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables, tomcat6

Sorry for such basic question but i am really confused.
After installing tomcat 6 , I found that I have to set `JAVA_HOME` and `CATALINE_HOME` .But what are `CLASSPATH` variables? In some tutorials , writer didn't mention to set but in some tutorials writer is saying to set them. Another confusionis that I found that somewhere they are set to `JAVA_HOME/lib` and somewhere `TOMCATHOME/lib`.I am really confused and want to understand the purpose and meaning of all of these variables.Thnaks

Comment: usually JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME are sufficient

Answer (score 0):

The `CLASSPATH` env varibale indicates the **locations** where the libraries will be looked for when needed.  This is more relevant when you are running a standalone java application.

Now, When you work with application servers like tomcat, you don't have have to worry about the libraries needed by your application running on Tomcat.

This is because, every application which is deployed on Tomcat (or other App Servers) has a **standard packaging structure** and there is a standard location where the libraries are stored. So for your case `CLASSPATH` is not relevant.

A typical application deployed on Tomcat is a WAR file, it has following structure ([Taken from here](http://www.openscope.net/2010/01/25/war-deployment-file-structure/)),

```
webapp.war
    |-- images/
    |   `-- banner.jpg
    |-- index.html
    |-- jsps/
    |   |-- public/
    |   |   `-- login.jsp
    |   `-- private/
    |       |-- application.jsp
    |       `-- settings.jsp
    `-- WEB-INF/
        |-- lib/
        |   `-- some-library.jar
        |-- classes/
        |   `-- compiled.class
        `-- web.xml
```

Here is a [good article](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat.html) for deployment on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` are not used by `Java` itself. Some third-party programs (for example Apache Tomcat) expect one of these environment variables to be set to the installation directory of the JDK or JRE.

`CLASSPATH` is an environment variable which contains a list of directories and / or JAR files, which Java will look through when it searches for Java classes to load. You do not normally need to set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Instead of using this environment variable, you can use the `-cp` option on the command line when using the javac and java commands.

below article will help you understand more details for tomcat class path

http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath